# Simple Excel Merge

Tags: python, excel

I'm starting baby steps on python and I have to merge 2 excel spread sheet books into just one. The books contain the same structure and they are in `.txt` format. Which quote do you recommend me to merge then, I have been working on this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


bd1 = pd.read_excel (r' \\C:..xls, sheet_name= "Sheet1")
bd2 = pd.read_excel (r' \\C:..xls, sheet_name= "Sheet1", header = 
"none",skiprows=1)

bd3_new= pd.merge('bd1','bd2')

bd3_new.to_excel(r'\\C....)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Noldo. What is the problem with your current solution? Is it working? Is it producing the wrong output? Is it dumping some stacktrace on the screen? (please update the question with more information instead of commenting or answering your own question)

Comment: The books contain the same structure and they are in `txt` format? If that's the case, they aren't Excel files.

Comment: Both above comments are correct - you need to look at delimited file type processing as .txt wouldn't be excel - your code is looking for .xls and you say they're in .txt format.